# Polar equation of perimeter of half ellipse

Tags: conic-sections, polar-coordinates

`x = Cx + a * cos(ang);`

`y = Cy + b * sin(ang);`

`Cx, Cy` are cords of center. `ang` is angle in radians. `a` is half of width, `b` is half of height.

If I change values of `ang`, I get different points on circumference of ellipse.
Below is the path which I get with above equation.

[image: Ellipse]

But instead of this elliptical shape, I want something like half ellipse, something like concave mirror. Even if we stretch both of its end to infinity, they should not form elliptical shape.

[image: Concave]

Can somebody provide me polar equations for second curve. I am very bad at digital drawing but you can imagine thas as concave mirror.

Comment: Did you obtain the entire ellipse by a suitable command or by a loop drawing concatenated segments ?

Comment: Actually, it's an equation of coordinates, if I change the angles, I'll get points on perimeter of ellipse.

Comment: The point is that polar equations for half an ellipse do not exist. One uses the same equations with a different range of the angle. Which software are you using ? I think you should edit to give an example of your operating.

Comment: I am using javascript and I want to move a point from bottom to top and I do not want the point to loop back to bottom. May be I need an equation for parabola which looks like half ellipse ? :O

Comment: Sure ! Around every vertex, an ellipse is essentially a parabola. Because of this fact, the motion of a projectile near the earth is parabolic in spite of Kepler's first law.